# Error while installing openstack on ubuntu 15.10 using devstack

Tags: software-installation, openstack

I have installed VMware player 12. But while executing this command `./stack.sh` to install openstack I am getting an error saying `./stack.sh: line 623: /home/aryan/devstack/.localrc.password: Permission denied`

Any help?
Here is the full message:

```
./stack.sh: line 623: /home/aryan/devstack/.localrc.password: Permission denied
++ /home/aryan/devstack/lib/database:initialize_database_backends:L104: get_database_type_mysql
++ /home/aryan/devstack/lib/databases/mysql:get_database_type_mysql:L28: [[ PyMySQL == \P\y\M\y\S\Q\L ]]
++ /home/aryan/devstack/lib/databases/mysql:get_database_type_mysql:L29: echo mysql+pymysql
+ /home/aryan/devstack/lib/database:initialize_database_backends:L104: BASE_SQL_CONN=mysql+pymysql://root:lukehunt@127.0.0.1
+ /home/aryan/devstack/lib/database:initialize_database_backends:L106: return 0
+ ./stack.sh:main:L642: echo 'Using mysql database backend'
Using mysql database backend
+ ./stack.sh:main:L651: RABBIT_USERID=stackrabbit
+ ./stack.sh:main:L652: is_service_enabled rabbit
+ /home/aryan/devstack/functions-common:is_service_enabled:L2025: local xtrace
++ /home/aryan/devstack/functions-common:is_service_enabled:L2026: set +o
++ /home/aryan/devstack/functions-common:is_service_enabled:L2026: grep xtrace
+ /home/aryan/devstack/functions-common:is_service_enabled:L2026: xtrace='set -o xtrace'
+ /home/aryan/devstack/functions-common:is_service_enabled:L2027: set +o xtrace
+ /home/aryan/devstack/functions-common:is_service_enabled:L2055: return 0
+ ./stack.sh:main:L653: RABBIT_HOST=192.168.0.144
+ ./stack.sh:main:L654: read_password RABBIT_PASSWORD 'ENTER A PASSWORD TO USE FOR RABBIT.'
+ ./stack.sh:read_password:L581: local xtrace
++ ./stack.sh:read_password:L582: set +o
++ ./stack.sh:read_password:L582: grep xtrace
+ ./stack.sh:read_password:L582: xtrace='set -o xtrace'
+ ./stack.sh:read_password:L583: set +o xtrace
touch: cannot touch '/home/aryan/devstack/.localrc.password': Permission denied
Error on exit
./stack.sh: line 488: generate-subunit: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit this link
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/
Create stack user to run devstack using

```
devstack/tools/create-stack-user.sh; su stack
```

And then start installing

```
cd devstack; ./stack.sh
```